# How to go about solving this question on differentials?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

1. A ring of a planet has an inner radius of approximately 52,000 km (measured from the center of the planet) and a radial width of 19 km. Use differentials to estimate the area of the ring. (Round your answer to the nearest thousand.)

I hate asking questions where I have nothing to contribute but I have absolutely no Idea on how to approach this question. A step by step solution to this problem which I could apply to similar problems would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: How would you find the area of the ring without calculus?

Comment: Using the formula $\pi(R^2-r^2)$? I just do not know how to apply it using differentials.

Comment: Yes,  that's good. One of the key ideas of calculus is that you can use the derivative to estimate how much a function changes when its input changes a little: $f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) \approx f'(x) \Delta x$. You can use this idea with the function $A(r) = \pi r^2$.

Comment: @littleO thanks, I'll see what I can do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could restate the problem as: "A circles radius increases from $a=52,000 \ \text{km}$ to $a=52,019 \ \text{km}$", and now all we need to do is find the estimate increase in the area. The area is given by $A=\pi r^2$, therefore 
$$\begin{align} dA&=A'(a)dr \\
&=2\pi a \  dr \\
&=2\pi(52,000)\cdot(19) \\
&\approx6,207,787.1\ \text{km}.
\end{align}$$

We know the true area is given by 
$$\begin{align}
\pi r_1^2 - \pi r_2^2 &= \pi((52,019)^2-(52,000)^2)\\
&\approx6208921.2 \ \text{km}. 
\end{align}$$

Thus, using differentials we see that the error in the estimate is around $1134.1$ km.

**Note.** We get the formula $dA=A'(a)dr$ if we wrtie $A=\pi r^2$ and note that $$\frac{dA}{dr}=2\pi r \Longrightarrow dA=2\pi r  \ dr.$$ We just changed $a$ to $r$ to distinguish the original radius $a$ from the change in the radius $dr$.