# How to use Differentials to find the area of a ring?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A ring of a planet has an inner radius of approximately 51,400 km (measured from the center of the planet) and a radial width of 17 km. Use differentials to estimate the area of the ring. (Round your answer to the nearest thousand.)

Comment: Differential is useful to compute little variations, in your case this toll is not appropriate. However, you can try the following: The desired area it is just the difference between the area of two circles.

Comment: so the inner radius and the radial width are two separate circles?

Comment: Try to draw two concentric circles...

Comment: ok. i drew them

Comment: I'm quite comfortable thinking of 17km as a "little" variation on the scale of 54,100km.

Comment: A _very_ similar question was asked the other day:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860713/how-to-go-about-solving-this-question-on-differentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look this figure:
[image]

Can you finish the question?

Comment: it would be pi[(51417^2)-(51400^2)]=5491155.24 or 5491000 for my answer?

Comment: $1747889\pi \approx 5491155.24$

Comment: You are welcome!